# C Typecast: How to

Tags: c, casting, overflow

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    unsigned short a,e,f ;    // 2 bytes data type
    unsigned int temp1,temp2,temp4; // 4 bytes data type
    unsigned long temp3; // 8 bytes data type
    a=0xFFFF;
    e=((a*a)+(a*a))/(2*a); // Line 8
    //e=(((unsigned long)(a*a)+(unsigned long)(a*a)))/(unsigned int)(2*a);    

    temp1=a*a;
    temp2=a*a;
    temp3=(unsigned long)temp1+(unsigned long)temp2; // Line 14
    temp4=2*a;

    f=temp3/temp4;

    printf("%u,%u,%lu,%u,%u,%u,%u\n",temp1,temp2,temp3,temp4,e,f,a);
    return(1);
}
```

How do I fix the arithmetic (At Line 8 by appropriate typecasting of intermediate results) so that overflows are taken care of ? Currently it prints 65534 instead of expected 65535.

Why is the typecast necessary for Line 14 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to promote the types *before* performing the overflowing operation. In line 8 that would be multiplication, so

```
e = ((unsigned) a * a + (unsigned) a * a) / (2 * (unsigned) a);
```

Note that promoting only one operand of such symmetrical operations as `*` is enough. You can use `(unsigned) a * (unsigned) a` if you wish, but `(unsigned) a * a` will work as well.

This will take care of multiplication, which will no longer overflow. However, now the addition will overflow. While 32-bit `unsigned` is enough for `a * a`, it is not enough for `a * a + a * a`. For that you'll need `unsigned long` (assuming it is larger). You can formally promote the first operand of `+` to `unsigned long`

```
e = ((unsigned long) ((unsigned) a * a) + (unsigned) a * a) / (2 * (unsigned) a);
```

(again, promoting only the first operand of `+` is enough, meaning that the second multiplication can be left in `unsigned`).

The above looks a bit too convoluted, and to make it look cleaner you can use `unsigned long` in the first multiplication from the very beginning

```
e = ((unsigned long) a * a + (unsigned) a * a) / (2 * (unsigned) a);
```

or you can just use `unsigned long` everywhere to make it look even cleaner

```
e = ((unsigned long) a * a + (unsigned long) a * a) / (2 * (unsigned long) a);
```

The very same problem appears in your `temp1 = a * a;` lines. They will overflow for the very same reason. You have to do

```
temp1 = (unsigned) a * a;
temp2 = (unsigned) a * a;
```

to avoid overflow, i.e. promote `a` *before* multiplication.

And that is exactly what you correctly do in line 14, i.e. promote operands of `+` *before* addition, although promoting only one operand is perfectly sufficient

```
temp3 = (unsigned long) temp1 + temp2;
```

Comment: `unsigned` isn't enough if it's 32 bits. The computation needs 33.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer: Right. Edited the answer.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I fix the arithmetic (At Line 8 by appropriate typecasting of intermediate results) so that overflows are taken care of ?

You need to cast one partner of both multiplications in the numerator to a large enough type. Since `(2^16-1)² = 2^32 - 2^17 + 1`, the numerator would overflow a 32-bit unsigned integer, hence you need something larger (typically that would be a 64-bit type). If `(unsigned) long` meets the size requirement,

```
e = (((unsigned long)a*a)+((unsigned long)a*a))/(2*a);
```

would be well-defined and safe (also with a cast to `long`, only 33 bits are needed here).

Using `unsigned long` is however not portable, because it may be a 32-bit type. Use `(unsigned) long long` or `(u)int_least64_t` to be portable and safe.

> Currently it prints 65534 instead of expected 65535.

That's because the result of the computation is `-2` if `int` is (as it very probably is) a two's complement 32-bit integer type with wrap-around behaviour on overflow [overflow of signed integers is undefined behaviour, though, so compiler optimisations could alter it; if the compiler analyses the computation and sees it's `2*a*a/(2*a)` it could simplify it to `a`, since that would be the result for any non-zero `a` where no overflow occurs; dividing by 0 is UB too, so all cases are covered].

```
(2^16-1)² = 2^32 - 2^17 + 1 ≡ -2^17 + 1 = -131071 (mod 2^32)
(-131071) + (-131071) = -262142
(-262142)/131070 = -2
```

The usual arithmetic conversions are applied to the operands of `*`, `+` and `/`, so the `unsigned short` operands are converted to `int` (since here all `unsigned short` values can be represented as `int`s), and the arithmetic is performed at type `int`.

The result `-2` is then converted to `unsigned short` by adding `USHRT_MAX +1` to it, resulting in `USHRT_MAX - 1` being the value of `e` afterwards.

> Why is the typecast necessary for Line 14 ?

because the addition of `temp1` and `temp2` would result in a value outside the 32-bit `unsigned` range, so the reduction modulo `2^32` of that result would change the overall result.

Answer (score 0):

You use "larger" types to begin with (i.e., don't declare `a` as an `unsigned short`, just declare it as an `unsigned int`).  If you need to cast then, well, just cast one side of an operation. The promotion will occur for you.